# How to implement GROUP BY aggregation with holistic aggregation if partitions do not fit into main memory?

Tags: optimization, group-by, aggregate, data-warehouse

Let's say I want to compute the **median** of some data given some grouping attributes G, e.g. the median price of all product sold daily (assuming a star-schema)

```
SELECT T.day_id, MEDIAN(price) 
FROM sales S, time T
WHERE T.day_id = S.day_id 
GROUP BY T.day_id;
```

Median is a **holistic aggregation function**, i.e. we can only compute it if we know all the records that belong to a certain day. How can this be computed if the records of one day does not fit into main memory?

**Edit:** I know what the median is and how to compute in general. I am interested in how to compute it efficiently, i.e. without producing much IO, when using GROUP BY. Also the median was just an example of a holistic function to make the question more concrete. I could also used other holistic aggregation functions such as rank, percentiles etc.

**What do i mean by holistic functions:**

A aggregation function is holistic if you can only compute it from their base elements or from a number of pre-aggregates that are not known in advance.
A counter example is the average. It is not holistic, because you always compute it by storing count and sum instead of storing all previous records.

Answer (score 2):

[Median value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is the value from the population where there's an equal number of values less than the median and greater than the median.  To perform that calculation, you don't need to have all values *in main memory*.  You simply need to order the values in either ascending or descending order, then pick the value that lies in the middle.

Even without using a sophisticated DBMS, it would be trivially easy to compute the median of a population of values by implementing a bubble-sort, reading and writing each value from-and-to disk as you process them.  This could be implemented in far less than 1 megabyte of RAM even for a list of many trillions of rows.  You need to clarify your question.

The answer to "is there any other solution" appears to me to be the same answer to the "P-NP" problem, which is currently unsolved, and people with far bigger brains than mine have looked at it for a long time.  In short, I have no way of conclusively proving there is no other "better" way to resolve this.  If you have a specific problem you are trying to solve, such as "the performance of *this* aggregate is too slow", then you should ask a new question with the specific details, including the DBMS in question, the table definitions, and code you have already built.

Comment: There's probably some variation of a trie index that solves the problem really fast (in O(logn) time)

Answer (score 1):

## SQL's "Ordered Set Function"

With PostgreSQL you can use the spec's [*Ordered-Set Aggregate Functions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE) to determine things like Median.

```
## Returns 2
SELECT percentile_disc(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x)
FROM ( VALUES (1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(3),(3),(3) ) AS t(x);

## Returns 3
SELECT percentile_disc(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x)
FROM ( VALUES (1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(3),(3),(3),(3) ) AS t(x);
```

Nothing here has to "fit into main memory?" At least no more than any other sequential scan would require.

[Microsoft has tried to implement "Ordered-Set Aggregates" too](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/ordered-set-functions-whats-new-and-missing-sql-server-vnext)